# Java Servlet framework that does things like rencoding images to preferred format etc

Tags: java, servlets, image-processing, servlet-filters

Are there any frameworks/libraries that provide servlets/filters etc that handle reencoding on the fly of images.

- interpret the accept headers and output the file, reencoding into the new format if necessary by checking the actual format of the original image file.
- provide a low and high quality version of an image.
- re encode an image into new dimensions. width and height parameters might query string parameters.

I could create versions of the file in all the formats, at upload time but the seems overkill. I would rather lazily create the rencoded file and stick it in a cache if it gets served again etc.

Comment: Standard Java can do that, you don't need a framework.

Comment: ok maybe f/w is a bit of overkill but a small lib would be nice. Im using f/w and lib interchangably.

Answer (score 1):

You donot need any framework. Do folowing:

1. Upload image. See [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)
2. Process the uploaded file using any of

   - [Java Advance Imaging](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/)
   - [Java wrapper for ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php?ImageMagick=qf426jpc764d2962u22p8pgsn0#java)
3. When processed, provide a link to download.

Comment: I dont know ahead of time what formats are necessary - i need to pick depending on what the user wants and test what i have and if necessary convert.

Comment: I am trying to react and deliver the desired formats the user agent gives rather than just giving the file i have.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick might be what you're after.  http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php, there's a java interface for it available here: http://www.jmagick.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As Nishants suggested .. I'd use Apache Commons FileUpload, once you get the image .. just convert it to any format you want

Comment: I dont know the formats that may be requested which is why i want it done dynamically.

Comment: And given i might want to reencode into a "lo" quality version it would be overkill to do all the versions on upload.

Answer (score 0):

You need no framework. Java has all you need:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        try {
          BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( new File( "/path/to/image.jpg" ) );
          ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);
        } finally {
          output.close();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Actually theres more one needs to read the accept-XXX (sorry cant recall exact name off the top of my head) and then decide to reencode. THen theres also the resizing thing. There are other extras yoou can do..